# What Runtime is Flash Builder using when running or debugging an AIR application?

Tags: flash, air, runtime

I just updated my AIR runtime to 3.0 and noticed that my AIR application doesn't work anymore. So I tried to debug it it with Flash Builder, but when I run it there, everything works just fine. So I uninstalled the AIR runtime completely but noticed that I can execute my AIR app within Flash Builder still just fine. So the AIR runtime used within Flash Builder seems to be a different one than the systemwide installed AIR runtime. How Do I chose within Flash Builder which runtime to use and how do I update this runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex SDK comes with it's own runtimes, but when debugging you use [ADL](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=CommandLineTools_4.html) executable (AIR Debug Launcher) from the /bin folder of the SDK you are compiling against (unless you defined a custom builder for you project).
Note that this link is to version 3 of the API, new API include options for multiscreen runtimes, but this should get you started.

This may sound weird, but I'd suggest you don't use Flash Builder's builder to compile projects, unless it's something very basic. If you need that kind of functionality, use your own builder. Adobe provides [Ant task](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=anttasks_3.html) for building Flex projects for this very purpose. So, I'd set Ant as the builder of the project and write a build file.

Comment: Will this allow me to debug an application that is compiled against AIR 2.x and makes trouble under AIR 3.0 runtime?